Quotation marks in .env file for Node.js project
I am basically copying and pasting a Fullstack (react/Node.js/Mysql) project from Youtube.
And I encountered a strange bug looks nowhere can find an answer
According to the video and all sources everywhere, that is the quotation marks in .env file.
Initially I followed the usual way, quotation mark outside a string, and I can not connect to my database:
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_USER = "root"

It takes me ages until I tried something like, and it worked:
DB_HOST = localhost
DB_USER = root

I am wondering why this happened? all I found is it does not matter if there is quotation marks in the .env file
Thanks in advance

This really depends on what is parsing the .env file. Is it dotenv, dotenvx, native Node.js --env-file, something else?

In general, the format should be KEY=value

Got it, cheers Phil!

Also, don't forget to use the new line at the bottom (empty line).
